# Can Rigid Carapaces be looted in Greece?

Tags: titan-quest

The Titan Quest Wiki, on its [Charms and Relics](https://titanquest.fandom.com/wiki/Charms_and_Relics) page, says that Rigid Carapaces can be acquired in Any Act...

But at looking at its list of monsters that drop it, I don't recognize any from Greece.

So, can Rigid Carapaces be found in Greece, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Titan Quest Wiki says that Rigid Carapaces can be acquired in any Act...

Where "Titan Quest Wiki" says that?

[Greece](https://titanquest.fandom.com/wiki/Greece) is first act. In [this wiki](https://titanquest.fandom.com/wiki/Rigid_Carapace) there are also listed farm areas and they are starting from act II. The monsters listed there are definitely not from act I. Also level requirement is 12 (has to look [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDa1UsOiwLE) to see level, poor wiki), which  *tells* somehow it won't be available from start.

So the answer is - nope, you won't get rigid carapases in act I normally.

Comment: https://titanquest.fandom.com/wiki/Charms_and_Relics - Any Act

Comment: @Malady, probably a mistake of one of contributors.

Comment: Yeah. Gonna checkmark your answer.